# How to pass ES6 rest parameters dynamically in d3.group

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, parameters

I am trying to group data in D3.js version 6.

```
d3.group(data, d=> d.Header, d=>Group);
```

This works fine but if I want to dynamically group data on multiple columns, How do I pass it?

```
function group(values, ...keys) {
  return nest(values, _identity_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default, _identity_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default, keys);
}
```

In d3.js library it expects rest parameters. Can someone help how to pass rest parameters in a function dynamically?

Comment: What about `nest(values, ...keys)`?

Comment: It does not work anymore with d3 version 6

Comment: Then the d3 function `nest` does not accept rest parameters? I can't find the method mentioned https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide               d3-collection is deprecated, and its methods are replaced:

d3.nest ⇨ d3.group and d3.rollup (from d3-array) [details]
d3.map ⇨ Map [details]
d3.set ⇨ Set [details]
d3.keys ⇨ Object.keys [details]
d3.values ⇨ Object.values [details]
d3.entries ⇨ Object.entries [details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is similar to your answer but it builds the array of functions within the call to `d3.group`

I've used `groups` in the example simply so it will log, but just change to `group` if you need the output as a nested `Map`:

```js
const data = [
  {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c1", "d": "d1", "v": 1},
  {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c2", "d": "d1", "v": 11},
  {"a": "a1", "b": "b2", "c": "c3", "d": "d1", "v": 21},
  {"a": "a1", "b": "b2", "c": "c4", "d": "d1", "v": 31},
  {"a": "a2", "b": "b3", "c": "c5", "d": "d1", "v": 41},
  {"a": "a2", "b": "b3", "c": "c6", "d": "d1", "v": 51},
  {"a": "a2", "b": "b4", "c": "c7", "d": "d1", "v": 61},
  {"a": "a2", "b": "b4", "c": "c8", "d": "d1", "v": 71}
];

const groupMulti = (data, ...keys) => {
  return d3.groups( //<--- change to group if you need Map as output
    data,
    ...keys.map(k => (d => d[k]))
  )
}

const arr = groupMulti(data, "a", "b");

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I could do it using .apply method to create arguments dynamically.

```
yColumns = ["column1", "column2"]
var arg = [oData.data];
yColumns.forEach(col => {
  var func = function(data){
      return data[col];
  }
  arg.push(func);
 });

 d3.group.apply(null,arg);
```